# Angular JS alternative xss payload?

Tags: xss, angularjs

Basically, I have a situation right now where the registration website allow to register via email address and then redirects me to another website (subdomain) of the original website. The subdomain website is using angular js and i was able to register an email address like {{1+1}}@example.com and it get printed as 2@example.com in the subdomain website while in the registration website the email is printed as {{1+1}}@example.com -

I'm trying to set an angular js payload into the email address field but the main domain say the email is invalid. The problem is caused by the brackets "()", i also tried to use %28 & %29 but they are not changed into "()" and so the injection is not occurring. Is there an alternative angular js xss payload without the use of the brackets "()"?

Are there any other exploitation for angular js injections or just xss?

Comment: Isn't angular JS only meant to handle front end rendering/user interaction?  Wouldn't this just be a potential XSS issue?  When you register, is that done via a POST or a GET?

Comment: @Daisetsu, It's done via a POST request on the main domain, the injection is occurring in the subdomain thou. I asked if there are other exploitations because if i set {{user.name}}@example.com it prints the name of the user@example.com